# Getting null values when reading data with PySpark but not with HUE

Tags: pyspark, hive, parquet

i'm trying to read partitioned data with PySpark but somehow for some partitions it gives me NULL values for all columns (except Partition column).

When I check the data in HUE/Hive, all is just fine. I've been googling the problem and found this:

https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Pyspark-Table-Dataframe-returning-empty-records-from/td-p/35836

which comes quite close to my problem but, if i'm not mistkane this refers only to self created data which is then stored in Parquet format. However, the table I want to read is in "EXTERNAL TABLE" format and I've managed to read it in with

`df = spark.read.parquet('hdfs location')`

but the result is the same. Any suggestions how to solve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: did you refresh, invalidate metadata, did this kind of operation ?

Comment: What do you mean with invalidate metadata? I refreshed HUE/Hive yes, but there the observations show up, but no in PySpark ... can I refresh Pyspark somehow?^^

Comment: Hive's default format is orc, not parquet. How do hdfs files look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, solved the issue by trying this: `sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet", "false")` from here: [Spark Hive SQL is Returning Empty Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61400368/spark-hive-sql-is-returning-empty-dataframe)